# Has anyone done a Javascript front end to a commercial rules engine?

Tags: javascript, css, less, pug, rule-engine

If so, did you use a JS templating framework (like Moustache or Jade) and CSS preprocessor (like LESS or Stylus) or let the BRE handle it all?

Comment: Take a look at rule.codeeffects.com. They've done interesting UI but it's not 100% client-side.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to use the rules engine to control the client side.
One example that does something like this is [TOHU](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Tohu).

> Tohu is an engine built on Drools to create dynamic UIs.  It is an alternative to the traditional MVC approach which instead uses a generic UI layer to render arbitrary UIs defined using simple business rules.

Comment: Any advice or alternative for Tohu in 2018? @Toni

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a product that uses a quite sophisticated rule engine, so that you can "drop in" a set of rules to radically change the behavior of the system without having to change the system code.

Initially our rule engine was .NET based, but we are now considering migrating to a JS rule engine so that we can execute both client and server side. Then we can use handlebars to keep the view in sync with the js model and bind the rules to model events.

Of course you'll want to double check server side that the rules executed on the client have been adhered to, so you can execute the same code server side to verify.